# HTML submission form will not submit when submit button is pressed UPDATED

Tags: html, forms, perl

I'm using FormMail through GoDaddy to process the form request, but it seems the sumbit button will not function correctly once all of the fields are entered. Below is the code that is used. If the fields are blank, the required notice is displayed, but it seems that when the fields are filled in, nothing happens. When the submit button is pressed, I want the page to go the redirect page (4th line of code below).

```
 <form id="contact-form" action="http://www.mydomain.com/formmail/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" method="post" >

  <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="me@mydomain.com" / >
   <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="WWW Message Form" / >
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.mydomain.com/index-6.html"/>

    <div class="success">
    Contact form submitted!<br>
    <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
    <label class="name">
     <input type="text" name="name" value="Name:">
     <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> 
    </label>
    <label class="email">
     <input type="text" name="email" value="E-mail:">
     <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
    </label>
    <label class="phone">
     <input type="tel" name="phone" value="Phone:">
     <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
    </label>
    <label class="message">
     <textarea name="message">Message:</textarea>
     <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
    </label>
    <div class="buttons-wrapper">
       <a class="button" data-type="reset">Clear</a>
       <a class="button" data-type="submit">Submit</a>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

I edited my original question. I'm using js to submit the form. Below is the variable declarations that need to be made. I need assistance figuring out what goes where.

```
var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                errorCl:'error',
                emptyCl:'empty',
                invalidCl:'invalid',
                notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                successCl:'success',
                successShow:'4000',
                mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                ownerEmail:'support@guardlex.com',
                stripHTML:true,
                smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                targets:'input,textarea',
                controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                validate:true
```

Comment: You tagged this as PHP, but your action leads to a PERL file `FormMail.pl` --- PHP and PERL are `two different animals` altogether. If your GoDaddy account doesn't let you run CGI/PERL then you can't run this. I take it from experience in the past, where someone I knew was with them, and their package did not include the use of those languages until they upgraded to another hosting package. (CGI-PERL)

Comment: My above comment btw, was just a quick FYI, just so you know. Am wondering also what permissions you've given it in order for it to run.

Comment: GoDaddy set the permissions for all users to full access, Exexcute, Read, and Write.

Comment: I used GoDaddy Windows Plesk Hosting to do this. The app was install via there portal.

Comment: Ah ok. I wasn't certain at first and since your question was originally tagged as PHP, I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
```

instead of

```
  <a class="button" data-type="submit">Submit</a>
```

Comment: This. You need a submit button, unless you want to submit the form programatically with javascript :)

Comment: I do want to submit it via js.